# How to show a Supabase table in Vue3

Tags: vuejs3, supabase, pinia

I'm learning Vue and Supabase, and I need to create a ToDo app. I did the auth and I can submit tasks to Supabase but I cannot make Supabase return me the tasks to print them in my component. I'm using Pinia also to store my functions. Please I need help because I don't understand why it's not working bc my class team have same codes.

I have this function in my component:

```
async function fetchAllTasks() {
  allTasks.value = await storeTasks.fetchTasks().value;
  console.log(allTasks.value);
}
fetchAllTasks();
```

this function is in my store:

```
 async fetchTasks() {
      const { data: tasks, error } = await supabase
        .from("tasks")
        .select("*")
        .order("id", { ascending: false });
      this.tasks = tasks;
    },
```

And this code in my template inside a table to show the tasks:

```
<tr v-for="task in allTasks" :key="task">
```

Comment: Does running fetchTasks() in a component return anything? If you console.log(error) does that show anything going on?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue using Nuxt3 trying to include pinia.

In my case, the supabase client was missing in the store and i could not declare it there.
I simply pass it as an argument from inside my component.

The function inside your store could be like this.

```
async fetchTasks(supabase) {
 //...code
}
```

And inside your component.

```
async function fetchAllTasks() {
  allTasks.value = await storeTasks.fetchTasks(supabaseClient).value;
  console.log(allTasks.value);
}
fetchAllTasks();
```

Do not know if this is a good way but hope I could help.